# Насколько большое значение играет подсистема MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Насколько большое значение играет подсистема MySQL? Например, мне нужно синхронизировать две базы данных с названием `events`. Т.е. даже не синхронизировать, а сделать так, чтобы у второй базы данных была структура, аналогичная структуре первой, а данные - из второй базы данных. И при сравнении схем в SQLyog'е (инструментом Schema Syncronyzation Tool) я вижу, что различия в структурах таблиц этих баз данных заключаются только в подсистемах (у первой `InnoDB`, у второй `MyISAM`):

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

USE `events`;

/* Alter table in target */
ALTER TABLE `eventlog` ENGINE=InnoDB; 
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
```

схема таблицы `eventlog` первой базы данных:

```
CREATE TABLE `eventlog` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `time` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `level` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message` blob NOT NULL,
  `description` blob,
  `flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

схема таблицы `eventlog` второй базы данных:

```
CREATE TABLE `eventlog` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `source` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `time` time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  `level` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `message` blob NOT NULL,
  `description` blob,
  `flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос, как скажется на работе приложения изменение подсистемы? Т.е. если приложение раньше работало с таблицами, созданными в подсистеме `MyISAM`, и начнёт работать с  таблицами, созданными в подсистеме `InnoDB`, это каким-нибудь образом отразится на производительности, безопасности и т.д.?

Comment: Отразится еще и как, `MyISAM` не транзакционный движок, а `InnoDB` транзакционный (если будете делать запись 10 значений в `InnoDB`, а на 10 будет ошибка, то изменения можно откатить, а с `MyISAM` нельзя). А т.к. в `MyISAM` нет транзакционности, то БД с ним будет работать значительно быстрее, но нет rollBack-а, и транзакций, что может привести к потере данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyISAM поддерживает сжатие таблиц в отличии от InnoDB.
MyISAM имеет встроенные полнотекстный поиск в отличии от InnoDB.
InnoDB поддерживает транзакции в отличии от MyISAM.
InnoDB поддерживает блокировки уровня строки (MyISAM - только уровня таблицы).
InnoDB поддерживает ограничения внешних ключей (MyISAM - нет).
InnoDB более надежна при больших объемах данных.
InnoDB в теории немного быстрее.
```

так-же советую http://itif.ru/otlichiya-myisam-innodb/

более подробно:
http://irbis-school.com/blog/full/21/vybor-dvizhka-bd-innodb-vs-myisam/2

и некоторые ньюансы
https://www.opennet.ru/tips/1958_mysql_myisam_innodb.shtml

Comment: У меня MyISAM показала значительно большую скорость чем InnoDB

Comment: В innodb уже давным давно завезли полнотекстовый поиск.

Comment: то что выделено было относительно давно, более новые могут варьироваться ! поэтому даны ссылки ! + надо смотреть версию СКЛь !!!